# Almacenar el valor de una variable

Tags: python, variables

necesito hacer una validación, cuyo parámetro se activa si se ingresa un numero primo, el problema es que solo se habilita si el ultimo numero fue primo, cuando yo quiero que sin importar el orden donde se introdujo, si alguno fue primo entonces se active el.
Ejemplo:
Mi variable se llama `self.primo = 0`
Se ingresan 5 números, si uno es numero primo, entonces `self.primo` se debe cambiar a 1
y luego se valida si `self.primo == 1`.
Sin embargo esto no pasa, ya que toma el valor dependiendo del ultimo numero

Este es el codigo:

```
class Numero():
    def __init__(self):
        self.primo = 0
        #self.des = True


    def camino(self, numero, a):
        arbol = 1
        if numero == 20:
            return f'Fruta = Achiote\n' \
                   f'Codice = {numero}\n' \
                   f'Arbol = {a}\n'

        if self.primo == 0:

            valor = range(2, numero)
            contador = 0
            for n in valor:
                if numero % n == 0:
                    contador += 1
                    #print("divisor:", n)

            if contador > 0:
                return f'Fruta = Ninguna\n' \
                       f'Codice = {numero}\n' \
                       f'Arbol = {a}\n'
            else:  
                self.primo = 1         #Aqui quiero que se vuelva uno si es primo, y que ese valor se mantenga
                return f'Fruta = Moras\n' \
                   f'Codice = {numero}\n' \
                   f'Arbol = {a}\n'

        else:
            return f'Fruta = Ninguna\n' \
                   f'Codice = {numero}\n' \
                   f'Arbol = {a}\n'

    def des(self):
        if self.primo == 1:    # Aqui valido ese dato
            return "Has sido atrapado por el jaguar"
        else:
            return "Has escapado del jaguar"


i = 0
while not i == 5:

    numero = int(input("¿Qué número quieres saber si es primo? "))
    a = i + 1
    miObjeto = Numero()
    #miObjeto.primo
    print(miObjeto.camino(numero, a))
    i += 1

print(miObjeto.des())
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, lo agradecería infinitamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada número por separado puede ser primo o no serlo. Por tanto es lógico que cada número tenga su propio atributo `.primo` indicando si lo es o no lo es. No tiene mucho sentido que el atributo `numero.primo`, en lugar de significar que el número en cuestión es primo, significa que otro número antes leido lo era. En todo caso el atributo podría llamarse `.hubo_primos`, pero no parece un atributo apropiado para una clase llamada `Numero`, si acaso una clase llamada `Juego`, o `Numeros`. Aunque a python le da igual cómo llames las cosas, a quien lea tu código no. Elegir buenos nombres es importante para comprender mejor lo que hace el código.

Para ver si un número es primo o no pruebas a ver si es divisible por algún número menor que él. No hace falta probar con todos, basta llegar hasta la raíz cuadrada del número. Para esto no necesitas una clase, sería más apropiada una función. Puedes hacer uso del decorador `@lru_cache` para que la implementación sea aún más eficiente (ese decorador hace que la función "recuerde" si ya había sido invocada para ese número y retorna en ese caso el valor recordado, en vez de tener que verificar otra vez si es primo o no).

Esta sería la idea:

```
from math import sqrt
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def es_primo(numero):
    primo = 1   # Primero suponemos que es primo
    for n in range(2, int(sqrt(numero))+1):
        if numero % n == 0:  # Pero si es divisible no lo es
           primo = 0
           break
    return primo
```

Por otro lado tu código implementa una especie de juego en la que según los números leidos se obtiene diferente resultado final en el juego. Creo que este juego podría implementarse en una clase, quizás llamada `Juego` en vez de `Numero`, que haga uso de la función anterior para ver si el número es primo o no. Esa clase sí podría tener un atributo llamado por ejemplo `.hubo_primos` para recordar si ya detectó alguno.

Esa clase se instanciaría una sola vez, antes de entrar al bucle, pues si instancias una nueva en cada iteración del bucle, el atributo `.hubo_primos` se resetearía a 0 en cada nueva instancia.

La idea sería por tanto:

```
class Juego:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hubo_primos = 0


    def camino(self, numero, a):
        arbol = 1            # ??? Esto no se usa
        if numero == 20:
            return f'Fruta = Achiote\n' \
                   f'Codice = {numero}\n' \
                   f'Arbol = {a}\n'

        if not es_primo(numero):
            return f'Fruta = Ninguna\n' \
                    f'Codice = {numero}\n' \
                    f'Arbol = {a}\n'
        else:
            self.hubo_primos = 1
            return f'Fruta = Moras\n' \
                f'Codice = {numero}\n' \
                f'Arbol = {a}\n'

    def des(self):
        if self.hubo_primos == 1:    # Aqui valido ese dato
            return "Has sido atrapado por el jaguar"
        else:
            return "Has escapado del jaguar"
```

Y el bucle principal podría ser algo como:

```
i = 0
juego = Juego()
while i != 5:
    numero = int(input("¿Qué número quieres saber si es primo? "))
    a = i + 1
    print(juego.camino(numero, a))
    i += 1

print(juego.des())
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!, estoy infinitamente agradecido, gracias por tomarse el tiempo de explicar tan bien la respuesta, ya que no solo soluciono el problema, si no que se logra entender a su totalidad, nuevamente, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

A cada iteración del bucle while estás creando un nuevo objeto Numero() con su variable self.primo = 0. Si lo que buscas es que si uno de los 5 números introducidos es primo, self.primo tenga el valor de 1 para todas las demás iteraciones que queden, puedes probar a inicializar el objeto `miObjeto` fuera del bucle para que no se cree uno nuevo a cada iteración.

```
i = 0
miObjeto = Numero()
while not i == 5:

    numero = int(input("¿Qué número quieres saber si es primo? "))
    a = i + 1
    #miObjeto.primo
    print(miObjeto.camino(numero, a))
    i += 1

print(miObjeto.des())
```